# Unity Carboard SDK Crash

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

I make an update including all Cardboard SDK feature into my game https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.oriongames.spaceshooter

BUT, I found that some Android device (not all, since my Note 2 and editor mode is working perfectly) Crash instantly after the Unity logo.

Here is the repport :

> java.lang.Error: FATAL EXCEPTION [UnityMain] Unity version : 5.1.1f1
>   Device model : samsung SM-T210 Device fingerprint:
>   samsung/lt02wifixx/lt02wifi:4.1.2/JZO54K/T210XXAMKF:user/release-keys
>
> Caused by: java.lang.Error: signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR),
>   fault addr 6ab6b090 Build fingerprint:
>   'samsung/lt02wifixx/lt02wifi:4.1.2/JZO54K/T210XXAMKF:user/release-keys'
>   Revision: '7' pid: 13587, tid: 13600, name: UnityMain >>>
>   com.oriongames.spaceshooter <<< r0 00000000 r1 00000000 r2 80808080 r3
>   6ab6b090 r4 6952f800 r5 6ab6a11c r6 5eb20520 r7 6ab6b090 r8 5eb20524
>   r9 5eb2056c sl 00000328 fp 69530190 ip 6ab5ed60 sp 5eb20500 lr
>   6a9a1979 pc 400ca174 cpsr 4b34354f
>
> at libc.strlen(strlen:72) at
>   libvrunity.ion::gfx::GraphicsManager::InitGlInfo()(gfx:136) at
>   libvrunity.ion::gfx::GraphicsManager::InitFunctions()(gfx:356) at
>   libvrunity.ion::gfx::GraphicsManager::Init(bool)(gfx:172) at
>   libvrunity.ion::gfx::GraphicsManager::GraphicsManager()(gfx:6010) at
>   libvrunity.gvr::VrSessionImpl::InitIonDefaults()(VrSessionImpl:124) at
>   libvrunity.gvr::CardboardVrSessionFactory::CreateCardboardVrSession(gvr::DisplayMetrics
>   const&, gvr::VrAppInfo const&, bool, std::function const&,
>   std::function const&)(CardboardVrSessionFactory:72) at
>   libvrunity.gvr::CardboardApiImpl::CardboardApiImpl(gvr::DisplayMetrics
>   const&)(CardboardApiImpl:182) at libvrunity.Start(Start:364) at
>   Unknown.0000eecc(Unknown Source) at BaseCardboardDevice.Start(Native
>   Method) at BaseCardboardDevice.Init(<0x00090>:144) at
>   CardboardAndroidDevice.Init(<0x0001b>:27) at
>   Cardboard.InitDevice(<0x00073>:115) at Cardboard.Awake(<0x00083>:131)
>   at Object.runtime_invoke_void__this__(Native Method) at
>   GameObject.Internal_AddComponentWithType(Native Method) at
>   GameObject.AddComponent(<0x00024>:36) at
>   GameObject.AddComponent(<0x0002b>:43) at
>   Cardboard.get_SDK(<0x000a3>:163) at
>   CameraManagerVRCardboard.Recenter(<0x00017>:23) at
>   c__IteratorD.MoveNext(<0x0009f>:159) at
>   .runtime_invoke_bool__this__(Native Method) at
>   MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(Native Method) at
>   MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine(<0x00028>:40) at
>   CameraManager.changeCameraState(<0x000b3>:179) at
>   StartMenu.Init(<0x00257>:599) at StartMenu.Start(<0x00043>:67) at
>   Object.runtime_invoke_void__this__(Native Method) at
>   libmono.00021bcf(Native Method) at
>   libmono.mono_runtime_invoke(mono_runtime_invoke:136) at
>   libunity.002b1e08(Native Method)

The game works again if I simply remove the Cardboard SDK from the game.

I try to changed GPU Skinning and Automatic Graphics API under PlayerPref but nothing works.

Do you have any clue ?
Thanks you !

Comment: Which version of Open GL ES are you using?  (Or do you have it set to Automatic?)

Comment: I tried all possibilities, Automatic and OpenGLES3 and 2 but nothing works.

I remove some object instance so it taks less memories and it seams to works from time to time. So maybe the cardboard sdk is just consuming too much memory ?